# Google Calendar Event: How do I (not the organizer) remove a room?

Tags: google-calendar-api

**Scenario:** I am taking over a number of events. The previous Organizer already set up the rooms for the events, but I wanted to change the rooms. I was able to add the rooms I wanted.

**Q:** Why can't I remove rooms I added as a non-organizer? Is it really just the Organizer who can make such changes? That just seems odd to me. Did I miss anything?

Comment: The reason why you can't update the calendar could be that the owner chose a [limited permission](https://support.google.com/calendar/forum/AAAAd3GaXpES1ZOs-jP2QI?hl=en) over other users even if this calendar was shared to anyone by the owner. [Learn more about sharing the calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't update the calendar could be that the owner chose a [limited permission](https://support.google.com/calendar/forum/AAAAd3GaXpES1ZOs-jP2QI?hl=en) over other users even if this calendar was shared to anyone by the owner. [Learn more about sharing the calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en).